# How to un-delete podcast episode in iOS 6 Podcasts app

Tags: ios, iphone, podcasts.app

I was deleting some old episodes of a podcast I like—just to get them out of the way in the episode queue—and I accidentally deleted an episode I wanted to keep. Problem is, it seems to be gone forever.

Swiping down on the page to refresh the list doesn't make episodes I've deleted reappear, and there's nothing in the show settings I can see that would allow me to re-download deleted episodes. It's effectively as if deleted episodes no longer exist, as far as my phone is concerned. I've force-closed the app and restarted my phone since discovering this, just in case. It made no difference.

Am I missing something obvious? What, if anything, can be done to un-delete deleted podcast episodes in the iOS 6 Podcasts app?

Comment: Im having the same issue, its weird cause my iphone will display different ones then my ipdad vs different ones in itunes its so bizzare if u figure out why lmk it sucks

Answer (score 1):

On the iPhone, tap the podcast in your list, then tap the header of the podcast to access the subscription settings. Simply toggle "off," then "on" for subscription and all the swiped-deleted podcasts will be restored.

Comment: this doesn't always work. I even deleted the entire podcast of my app, then searched and subscribed to it again and it still didn't work. It looks like it works for some podcasts but not all.

Answer (score 1):

On iOS 7, tap the podcast in your list, then tap the header of the podcast to access the subscription settings.

After this, swipe up to scroll all the way to the bottom of your episodes, then choose "Add Old Episodes," checkmark the episode(s) you want to get back, then choose "Add."

Answer (score 0):

Is it a podcast available in the iTunes Store? I've made the same mistake and fixed it by going to the podcast's page and downloading the episode.

Answer (score -1):

At the bottom of a list is a button reading "Add Old Episodes" which allows you to add anything you have deleted manually.